# drop function not working

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I want to save the images by using both drag and drop and also click function.I wrote the script for both click function and drop function. Click function work properly but drop function not does not work.I don't know where is the mistake..

```
<div align="center">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
           <div id="dock" class="dock">

            Drag & Drop Photos Here</div>

            </div>
```

Below , its my javascript function.I called the two ajax function.one for click function and another for drop function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#dock").click(function(){
                    $("#file").click();
                });

                       $("#file").change(function(){
                    var fd = new FormData();
           var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
            fd.append('file',files);
           uploadData(fd);
                });
                    $('#dock').on('dragenter', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });  
                    $('#dock').on('drop', function(e){ t
                        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {

                            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) { 
                                e.preventDefault();
                                e.stopPropagation();
                            upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    function upload(files){
                    var fd1 = new FormData();
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
                fd1.append('file_' + i, files[i]); 
                        }
                        fd1.append('nbr_files', i); 
                        $.ajax({ // JQuery Ajax
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'ajax/tuto-dd-upload-image.php',
                            data: fd1, 
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(data) {
                             alert(data);
                                $('#result').html(data);

                            },

                        });
                    }
                function uploadData(formdata){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: formdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
        });
```

Comment: and you get an error? what is the error? or nothing happens? checked your if conditions?

Comment: I can't the drop the images.When I drag over the images the images will be disabled.. :(